# Converting nested tuple to list in elixir

Tags: elixir

trying to do:

```
def nested_tuple_to_list(tuple) when is_tuple(tuple) do
  ...
end
```

expecting to get:

```
    iex> example = {"foo", "bar", {"foo", "bar"}}
    iex> example_as_list = nested_tuple_to_list(example)
    iex> example_as_list
    ["foo", "bar", ["foo", "bar"]]
```

my question is what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library that can do this and many other transforms of nested data.

```
iex(1)> h PhStTransform.transform

        def transform(data_structure, function_map, depth \\ [])
```

uses the given `function_map` to transform any Elixir `data structure`.

`function_map` should contain keys that correspond to the data types to be
transformed. Each key must map to a function that takes that data   type and optionally the depth list as arguments.

`depth` should always be left at the default value since it is meant for internal recursion.

Examples

```
iex> atom_to_string_potion = %{ Atom => fn(atom) -> Atom.to_string(atom) end }
iex> PhStTransform.transform([[:a], :b, {:c, :e}], atom_to_string_potion)
[["a"], "b", {"c", "e"}]

iex> foo = {"foo", "bar", {"foo", "bar"}}
{"foo", "bar", {"foo", "bar"}}

iex> PhStTransform.transform(foo, %{Tuple => fn(tuple) -> Tuple.to_list(tuple) end})
["foo", "bar", ["foo", "bar"]]
```

https://hex.pm/packages/phst_transform

Answer (score 9):

Use `Tuple.to_list/1` and map the resulting list with the same function, and add a fallback clause for non-tuple inputs:

```
defmodule A do
  def nested_tuple_to_list(tuple) when is_tuple(tuple) do
    tuple |> Tuple.to_list |> Enum.map(&nested_tuple_to_list/1)
  end
  def nested_tuple_to_list(x), do: x
end

{"foo", "bar", {"foo", "bar"}} |> A.nested_tuple_to_list |> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
["foo", "bar", ["foo", "bar"]]
```

If you want to transform tuples inside lists as well, you can add:

```
def nested_tuple_to_list(list) when is_list(list) do
  list |> Enum.map(&nested_tuple_to_list/1)
end
```

This can be easily extended to handle Maps as well.